# Input type="button" скачивание файла

Tags: html

Простите за нубский вопрос, но что-то меня кальнуло, и гугл ответ не дал, но можно ли сделать при нажатии на кнопку скачивание файла с сайта? Можно сделать так:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite" class="but">     Скачать файл</a>
```

а можно ли сделать так:

```
  <input type="button" value="скачать" src="http://www.###">
```

не применяя js (без onclick).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через формы:

```
<form action='http://file'>
    <input type='submit' value='Скачать'>
</form>
```